# How to access the video in iPhone synched through iTunes from PC

Tags: ios, swift, video, phasset

I'm trying to access the video in my iPhone which is imported from my PC through iTunes but I cannot.

I tried the following code but it doen't work.

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.includeAssetSourceTypes = .TypeiTunesSynced
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Video, options: fetchOptions)
```

I also tested the following code. I can access the videos in Camera roll, but not the video synched through iTunes from PC.

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Video, options: fetchOptions)
```

I'd really appreciate if you can give me some advice.

**UPDATE**
The following code works. Thanks for your advice!

```
import MediaPlayer
```

and

```
let mediaTypeNumber = MPMediaType.AnyVideo.rawValue
let query = MPMediaQuery()
query.addFilterPredicate(MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: mediaTypeNumber, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType))

let items: [MPMediaItem] = query.items! as [MPMediaItem]
for item in items {
    // If you want to get title.
    let title = item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as! String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access those videos using PhotoKit. PhotoKit only allows access to media stored in the central Photo Library - in short: everything that is shown in the Photos App.

Videos synced by iTunes are part of the Music(iPod)-Library. You can access these through the MPMediaLibrary:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaLibrary_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMediaLibrary

Comment: Thanks for your advice, you saved me a lot. I added my code for the reference.